# Can two clauses joined by masu-stem form have an reason-action relationship?

Tags: parsing

> 新しい駅は、品川駅と田町駅の間にある車両基地の一部を縮小し**建設が進められていて**、山手線と京浜東北線の列車が停車する計画です。
>   The new station will reduce part of the rail yard between the Shinagawa and Tamachi stations and 建設が進められていて and it is planned that Yamanote line Keihintouhoku line trains will stop *there*.

I have no idea how 建設が進められていて fits into this sentence. I can only translate it as "by means of construction proceeding ..."i.e. the act of construction proceeding is the way that trains will stop at the station. Well, that seems so obvious that it doesn't need to be said. If you don't finish building the station then no trains will be stopping there.

Or maybe the sentence is just saying three separate things strung together into one incoherent sentence. "The station will reduce the rail yard **and** construction is progressing **and** trains will stop there".

I feel I must have completely misunderstood/mis-parsed this sentence.

I also feel a bit weird about translating 縮小 as 'reduce'. 'Occupy' or 'replace' would seem like more natural words to use in English. Is there any way I can think of 縮小する to make it seem more natural?

Putting my two concerns together I have a final hypothesis that 車両基地の一部を縮小し and 建設が進められていて go together to give "Construction is proceeding that will reduce part of the railyard and ... If that is so then I didn't know you could join two clauses with the masu-stem form (I don't know the real name for this) where the first clause is the purpose of the second clause.

Comment: Two questions, two down votes today. Would you please tell me what you find unsatisfactory.

Comment: 'Streamlining' might be a decent translation for 縮小. I didn't downvote you, but it is unrealistic to expect an answer to your question of why you were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not parsed the sentence correctly. The first half of this sentence is a "double-subject" clause:

> 新しい駅は建設が進められていて、...
>   (literally) As for the new station, construction is being proceeded, (and ...)

And 品川駅と田町駅の間にある車両基地の一部を縮小し is adverbially modifying 建設が進められる. It can be rephrased as 品川駅と田町駅の間にある車両基地の一部を縮小**することで** ("by partially reducing the size of the rail yard located between Shinagawa and Tamachi stations).

It says 縮小 because only a part of the rail yard will be used for the new station. (This rail yard is large; check it on Google Map if you are interested.)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 sentences, all with the same topic:

新しい駅は...基地の一部を縮小する。
The new station will reduce part of the yard.

新しい駅は建設が進められている。
The construction of the new station is advancing.

新しい駅は...列車が停車する計画です。
It is planned for the trains to stop at the new station.